# How to convert to_date() SQL Function to T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I have a query for Oracle data which has `TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY')` in it. I need to run the same query on SQL Server, but I am facing a problem since the `TO_DATE()` function is not available for T-SQL.

Can someone please help me with the equivalent of to_date() function which does the same as `TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY').`

Original SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO LOC_CLOSING_MESSAGE 
VALUES (2, 1, 'Store One.', TO_DATE('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY'),
       'TEST_USER', SYSDATE, 'TEST_USER', NULL)
```

Comment: See this http://www.sqlines.com/oracle-to-sql-server/to_date

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `CONVERT` function because it allows you to specify the format that you want to convert to.

In your case that would be:

```
INSERT INTO LOC_CLOSING_MESSAGE
  VALUES (2, 1, 'Store One.', 
    CONVERT('01-JAN-2017', 'DD-MON-YYYY', 105),
    'TEST_USER', SYSDATE,
    'TEST_USER', NULL
);
```

For list of all `CONVERT` formats, check out [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/).

**NOTE:** Since I don't know what data type is your fourth attribute in table `LOC_CLOSING_MESSAGE` is, I don't really know if this formatting part is even needed in your case. Nevertheless, it can't hurt and gives you **exactly** what you asked for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO LOC_CLOSING_MESSAGE VALUES (2, 1, 'Store One.', CONVERT(DATETIME, '01-JAN-2017'), 'TEST_USER', SYSDATE, 'TEST_USER', NULL)
```